# Generic Logging Method

Tags: java, design-patterns

Is this a good thing to do; to log via a method like this?

```
public static void log(final Object... messages) {
    logger.info(Joiner.on(',').useForNull("null").join(messages));
}
```

//  Where  in other parts of code we can call the logger method using commas instead of string concatenation. Please note Joiner is a guava class.

```
log(" Check ",obja.getXXX(),anotherObject.getMethod());
```

Expectation is clean code, convenience and performance.

Comment: I would add a second parameter that allows you to specify the severity of the log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably want to join on `' '` (blank) rather than comma but the design approach is a nice idea.

Performance wise, it's not ideal. You create an additional object array and a joiner plus the internal buffers of the joiner.

So you can just get 2 of 3 with this approach. If you really care about performance, use [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/) which already uses a similar approach.

Answer (score 4):

I use [SLF4J's `Logger`](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/Logger.html) interface (with [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/) implementation), which I find much cleaner to read.

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Test {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Test.class);

    public void method(String name, int age, Address address) {
        logger.info("Person {}, age {} years old resides at {}", name, age, address);
    }
}
```

Comment: @ adarshr I would definetly try SLF4J as soon as I get a chance. ty.

Answer (score 2):

SLF4J's interface is better, like other answers say.

I'm not understanding how this is a performance improvement. Maybe the OP has a specific use case in mind and some example code would explain it. If the idea is to collect messages upfront and send them together to a log method invocation, then you'd be better served using an appender that does buffering.